# Сглаживание моделей Blender для Unity

Tags: unity3d, blender

Как можно сгладить модели где используется Bevel(Ctrl+B) для Unity, можно заметить, что сдандартные модели unity, к примеру Cylinder имеют мало треугольников, но выглядят гладко, как можно добиться такого эффекта в blender?

Comment: Для этого нужно добавлять большее количество делений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Количество граней нужно делать минимальным для игрового движка.

В режиме объекта в контекстном меню выберите Shade Smooth

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На панели Object Data нужно включить Auto Smoth

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в конце добавьте модификатор Weighted Normal со стандартными настройками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]